# Coded UI Property from a Label, but the label.text value did not change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I hope you can Help me with this.

I'm doing an Automation script in VS 2012 with C# and I need change the value of a Property so I'm doing this

```
                HtmlLabel htmlLabel = new HtmlLabel(tableDocuments);
                htmlLabel.FilterProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = taginstanceCount.ToString();
                UITestControlCollection lblCollection = htmlLabel.FindMatchingControls();

                HtmlLabel desiredLabel = (HtmlLabel)lblCollection[0];
```

But when I Watch in VS the
    **desiredLabel.TagInstance** the value is 9 and the value of the **taginstanceCount.ToString()** is **7**, So when the script try to do click in the document that I indicate that is the document with **TagInstace = 7** isn't is doing click in the **taginstanceCount.ToString()**. I hope you can help me with this problem.

> html code behind

```
<span class="field"> <label class="checkbox document-check" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px;" for="check2"> 
<input name="checkbox[]" id="documentID" type="checkbox" value="2" data-internalid="161"> 
<span></span> 
</label> </span>
```

This is the declaration of the tableDocument

```
HtmlTable tableDocuments = this.UIAllianceUnitedInternWindow.UIAllianceUnitedDocument.UIIFramedataFrame2.UIAllianceUnitedDocument.UIDocumentsTabPane.tableDocuments;
```

Regards.

Comment: have you checked out the documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.htmlcontrols.htmllabel.aspx can you show the html markup for this

Comment: @DJ FRAZE Yes I checked the Documentation but I don't find nothing to help me, I just want to know if I'm doing something wrong in the code.

Comment: I am wondering if you could show your html markup is there possibly an issue with tag and or Id ..just curious

Comment: Ok I think this is what you mean
    <span class="field">
            <label class="checkbox document-check" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px;" for="check2">
                <input name="checkbox[]" id="documentID" type="checkbox" value="2" data-internalid="161">
                <span></span>
            </label>
        </span>

Comment: place that in your original question it's hard to read..if not I will update it for you

Comment: also where is this being assigned ...? `tableDocuments`

Comment: Here HtmlTable tableDocuments = this.UIAllianceUnitedInternWindow.UIAllianceUnitedDocument.UIIFramedataFrame2.UIAllianceUnitedDocument.UIDocumentsTabPane.tableDocuments;

I'm get all the Table information and is working, but the problem is when I tried to assign a new value to the TagInstance in the Label

Comment: don't place your code in the comments edit your original question and paste the code where you originally pasted your code...